# Joomla website is getting 303 redirect loop

Tags: redirect, joomla

My website is sometimes getting a 303 redirect loop on the main page. This gives me an error when trying to view the site "the webpage has a redirect loop", but most of the time is loads fine. But, the 303 redirect doesn't look good for SEO. I'm running the Joomla 3.2.3 with the Zo2 framework. I used the firefox live http headers tool and this is what it shows:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See other
Date: Sat, 19 Apr 2014 06:42:44 GMT
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.26
Set-Cookie: 81f5073a1f9d10dc244e07c98216335e=hb7mb5k3v0vftstcgtdbonikq6; path=/;         HttpOnly
Location: /
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Expires: Sat, 19 Apr 2014 06:52:44 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I went through and disable every plugin in Joomla one at a time and when I disable the Zo2 framework plugin the 303 redirect went away. I've asked on their forums and they haven't been able to help me. So, I searched through all of the files in the zo2 plugin directory for the word redirect and this is what I found.

These two are in the site.megamenu.js

```
!function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        // when clicking on menu
        redirect();
        var duration = 0;
        var $parent = $('.zo2-megamenu');
        var hover_type = $parent.data('hover');
        if ($parent.data('duration')) {
            duration = $parent.data('duration');
        }

function redirect() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click',function(e){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('open') && this.href && this.href != '#'){
            window.location.href = this.href;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}
```

I have other website running on this server using the same .htaccess and php.ini files so I don't think that could be the problem, because they are not getting a redirect. I would appreciate some help with this. The website is http://www.betterfreestuff.com

```
/**
 * Zo2 Framework (http://zo2framework.org)
 *
 * @link     http://github.com/aploss/zo2
 * @package  Zo2
 * @author   Hiepvu
 * @copyright  Copyright ( c ) 2008 - 2013 APL Solutions
 * @license  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or Later
 */

!function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        // when clicking on menu
        redirect();
        var duration = 0;
        var $parent = $('.zo2-megamenu');
        var hover_type = $parent.data('hover');
        if ($parent.data('duration')) {
            duration = $parent.data('duration');
        }

        if (duration && (hover_type == 'hover')) {
            var timeout = duration ? duration + 50 : 500;
            $('.nav > li, li.mega').hover(
                function(e) {
                    onMouseIn(this, timeout);
                }
                ,
                function (e) {
                    onMouseOut(this);
                }
            );
        } else if (hover_type == 'click') {

            $('.mega-nav').find('.dropdown-submenu').hover(
                function(e) {
                    onMouseIn(this, 100);
                }
                ,
                function (e) {
                    onMouseOut(this);
                }

            );

        }
        // for first li tag
        function redirect() {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click',function(e){
                if($(this).parent().hasClass('open') && this.href && this.href != '#'){
                    window.location.href = this.href;
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
        function onMouseIn (e, timeout) {

            var $this = $(e);
            if ($this.hasClass('mega')) {
                $this.addClass ('hovering');
                clearTimeout ($this.data('hoverTime'));
                $this.data('hoverTime',
                    setTimeout(function(){$this.removeClass ('hovering')}, timeout));

                clearTimeout ($this.data('hoverTime'));
                $this.data('hoverTime',
                    setTimeout(function(){$this.addClass ('open')}, 100));
            } else {
                clearTimeout($this.data('hoverTime'));
                $this.data('hoverTime',
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.addClass('open')
                    }, 100));
            }

        }

        function onMouseOut (e) {
            var $this = $(e);
            clearTimeout($this.data('hoverTime'));
            $this.data('hoverTime',
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $this.removeClass('open')
                }, 100));

        }

        /** BEGIN: off canvas menu **/
        var showOffCanvasMenu = function () {
            var $offcanvas = $('.offcanvas');
            var $body = $('body');
            var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

            $body.addClass('overflow-hidden');
            $wrapper.addClass('offcanvas-push');

            var $overlay = $('<div />').addClass('offcanvas-overlay').appendTo('body');
            $overlay.css({
                top:0,
                right:0,
                bottom:0
            }).fadeIn();

            $overlay.click(function() {
                $body.removeClass('overflow-hidden');
                $wrapper.removeClass('offcanvas-push');
                $offcanvas.removeClass('active');
                $('.offcanvas-overlay').remove();
            });
        };
        var hideOffCanvasMenu = function () {
            var $body = $('body');
            var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
            var $offcanvas = $('.offcanvas');

            $body.removeClass('overflow-hidden');
            $wrapper.removeClass('offcanvas-push');
            $offcanvas.removeClass('active');
            $('.offcanvas-overlay').remove();
        };
        $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
            var $offcanvas = $('.offcanvas');
            $offcanvas.toggleClass('active');

            if ($offcanvas.hasClass('active')) {
                showOffCanvasMenu();
            }
            else {
                hideOffCanvasMenu();
            }
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.sidebar-nav a', function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('nav-oc-toggle')) hideOffCanvasMenu();
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.sidebar-close', function() {
            hideOffCanvasMenu();
        });

        // new off canvas submenu
        $('body').on('click', '.nav-oc-toggle', function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $parent = $this.closest('.nav-parent');

            if ($parent.find('> .submenu').hasClass('in')) $this.removeClass('icon-caret-up').addClass('icon-caret-down');
            else $this.removeClass('icon-caret-down').addClass('icon-caret-up');
        });
        /** END: off canvas menu **/
    });
}(jQuery);
```

I searched for 303 in all of the files on my server and these files came back with redirect statements.

cms.php

```
public function redirect($url, $moved = false)

{
    // Handle B/C by checking if a message was passed to the method, will be removed at 4.0
if (func_num_args() > 1)
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    /*
     * Do some checks on the $args array, values below correspond to legacy redirect() method
     *
     * $args[0] = $url
     * $args[1] = Message to enqueue
     * $args[2] = Message type
     * $args[3] = $moved
     */
    if (isset($args[1]) && !empty($args[1]) && !is_bool($args[1]))
    {
        // Log that passing the message to the function is deprecated
        JLog::add(
            'Passing a message and message type to JFactory::getApplication()->redirect() is deprecated. '
            . 'Please set your message via JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage() prior to calling redirect().',
            JLog::WARNING,
            'deprecated'
        );

        $message = $args[1];

        // Set the message type if present
        if (isset($args[2]) && !empty($args[2]))
        {
            $type = $args[2];
        }
        else
        {
            $type = null;
        }

        // Enqueue the message
        $this->enqueueMessage($message, $type);

        // Reset the $moved variable
        $moved = isset($args[3]) ? (boolean) $args[3] : false;
    }
}
```

application.php

```
public function redirect($url, $msg = '', $msgType = 'message', $moved = false)
    {
        // Check for relative internal links.
        if (preg_match('#^index2?\.php#', $url))
        {
            $url = JUri::base() . $url;
        }

        // Strip out any line breaks.
        $url = preg_split("/[\r\n]/", $url);
        $url = $url[0];

        /*
         * If we don't start with a http we need to fix this before we proceed.
         * We could validly start with something else (e.g. ftp), though this would
         * be unlikely and isn't supported by this API.
         */
        if (!preg_match('#^http#i', $url))
        {
            $uri = JUri::getInstance();
            $prefix = $uri->toString(array('scheme', 'user', 'pass', 'host', 'port'));

            if ($url[0] == '/')
            {
                // We just need the prefix since we have a path relative to the root.
                $url = $prefix . $url;
            }
            else
            {
                // It's relative to where we are now, so lets add that.
                $parts = explode('/', $uri->toString(array('path')));
                array_pop($parts);
                $path = implode('/', $parts) . '/';
                $url = $prefix . $path . $url;
            }
        }

        // If the message exists, enqueue it.
        if (trim($msg))
        {
            $this->enqueueMessage($msg, $msgType);
        }

        // Persist messages if they exist.
        if (count($this->_messageQueue))
        {
            $session = JFactory::getSession();
            $session->set('application.queue', $this->_messageQueue);
        }

        // If the headers have been sent, then we cannot send an additional location header
        // so we will output a javascript redirect statement.
        if (headers_sent())
        {
            echo "<script>document.location.href='" . str_replace("'", "&apos;", $url) . "';</script>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $document = JFactory::getDocument();

            jimport('phputf8.utils.ascii');

            if (($this->client->engine == JApplicationWebClient::TRIDENT) && !utf8_is_ascii($url))
            {
                // MSIE type browser and/or server cause issues when url contains utf8 character,so use a javascript redirect method
                echo '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=' . $document->getCharset() . '" />'
                    . '<script>document.location.href=\'' . str_replace("'", "&apos;", $url) . '\';</script></head></html>';
            }
            else
            {
                // All other browsers, use the more efficient HTTP header method
                header($moved ? 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' : 'HTTP/1.1 303 See other');
                header('Location: ' . $url);
                header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $document->getCharset());
            }
        }

        $this->close();
    }
```

web.php

```
public function redirect($url, $moved = false)
{
    // Import library dependencies.
    jimport('phputf8.utils.ascii');

    // Check for relative internal links.
    if (preg_match('#^index\.php#', $url))
    {
        // We changed this from "$this->get('uri.base.full') . $url" due to the inability to run the system tests with the original code
        $url = JUri::base() . $url;
    }

    // Perform a basic sanity check to make sure we don't have any CRLF garbage.
    $url = preg_split("/[\r\n]/", $url);
    $url = $url[0];

    /*
     * Here we need to check and see if the URL is relative or absolute.  Essentially, do we need to
     * prepend the URL with our base URL for a proper redirect.  The rudimentary way we are looking
     * at this is to simply check whether or not the URL string has a valid scheme or not.
     */
    if (!preg_match('#^[a-z]+\://#i', $url))
    {
        // Get a JUri instance for the requested URI.
        $uri = JUri::getInstance($this->get('uri.request'));

        // Get a base URL to prepend from the requested URI.
        $prefix = $uri->toString(array('scheme', 'user', 'pass', 'host', 'port'));

        // We just need the prefix since we have a path relative to the root.
        if ($url[0] == '/')
        {
            $url = $prefix . $url;
        }
        // It's relative to where we are now, so lets add that.
        else
        {
            $parts = explode('/', $uri->toString(array('path')));
            array_pop($parts);
            $path = implode('/', $parts) . '/';
            $url = $prefix . $path . $url;
        }
    }

    // If the headers have already been sent we need to send the redirect statement via JavaScript.
    if ($this->checkHeadersSent())
    {
        echo "<script>document.location.href='" . str_replace("'", "&apos;", $url) . "';</script>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        // We have to use a JavaScript redirect here because MSIE doesn't play nice with utf-8 URLs.
        if (($this->client->engine == JApplicationWebClient::TRIDENT) && !utf8_is_ascii($url))
        {
            $html = '<html><head>';
            $html .= '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=' . $this->charSet . '" />';
            $html .= '<script>document.location.href=\'' . str_replace("'", "&apos;", $url) . '\';</script>';
            $html .= '</head><body></body></html>';

            echo $html;
        }
        else
        {
            // All other cases use the more efficient HTTP header for redirection.
            $this->header($moved ? 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' : 'HTTP/1.1 303 See other');
            $this->header('Location: ' . $url);
            $this->header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $this->charSet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I could still use some help with this.

Comment: 303 isn't necessarily an error and depending on the plugins purpose could be the desired behavior.  My guess is that the this.href isn't properly populating the correct 303 url.  Can you post the entire JS file so we can see where this.href is being assigned?

Comment: Here is the entire site.megamenu.js file. I added it to the original question. You say that 303 isn't an error, but wont it hurt my site with Google?

Comment: To clarify, the 303 in and of itself is not an error.  It is an legitimate response code part of the HTML 1.1 specification and you can read up about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303.  The loop error you are experiencing however appears to be an incorrect application of the 303 and most certainly can cause issues with Google.  I'll review the posted JS when I have a moment and see if I can pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I did a little more research and added some additional information to the first post. Don't know if it will help.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help did you see anything wrong with the scripts I posted?